# Mac Dual Monitor: Prevent Second monitor to go black while first one is fullscreen

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors

Is there a way to prevent the second monitor to turn black when an application in the first monitor is made full screen?  I have this problem in Mac.

Comment: there's not enough info in your question. What monitors? What connection type? What Mac and OS version? Please update.

Answer (score 33):

Yes there is (And if you use a Mac, I also believe that there is enough information on the issue to answer the question).

Just go to System Preferences > Mission Control  and check the option that says "Displays have separate Spaces".

[image: Separate Spaces]

That solves the issue on one monitor going black when there is an app on fullscreen mode in the other.

Comment: Note that relogging is required for this to work. "Requires log out" is visible on the screenshot you're linking to, but not in the settings dialog I'm actually getting.

Comment: Note that turning on "Displays have separate Spaces" prevents application windows from spanning more than one screen.  You cannot have that and useful full screen on multiple monitors at the same time.  OS X's multi screen/monitor/desktop and full screen implementation choices are fundamentally broken.  A window manager add-on that does "manual" vs native full screen like Divvy is a reasonable workaround if the app doesn't have "special" full screen behavior you need.

Comment: My Firefox on macOS 10.14.6 will full-screen only on one monitor/display _even if_ `Displays have separate Spaces` is unchecked (and I prefer to keep it unchecked per the above issues that @Metaxis mentions above). No other web-browser can do this, on my system anyway.

Comment: This checkbox does not help me in BigSur when using Firefox. The only way I found to work is to use another browser in another screen.

Comment: I do not really see this as a solution. I do not want to have separate spaces on different displays. I just do not want my 2nd screen go black if the first one has fullscreen app.

Comment: Seven years later and this is still an issue, are there any solutions to this besides enabling "Displays have separate spaces"?

Comment: Wait a second here. I'm getting the same issue on Ventura and the answer isn't a solution if you want to span your desktop across multiple monitors.