# How to Black Out One of Two Displays on MacOS?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, macos-catalina

We have the reverse problem to the OP in this question ([Mac Dual Monitor: Prevent Second monitor to go black while first one is fullscreen](https://superuser.com/questions/979935/mac-dual-monitor-prevent-second-monitor-to-go-black-while-first-one-is-fullscre/1019391)). He is asking how to prevent black out of the primary display when there is a fullscreen app on the secondary display. Wish we had this problem...

We *want* the primary display to be blacked out when playing (VLC) full-screen on the secondary screen. (The primary screen is the iMac itself, the secondary screen is a MiniDisplayPort to HDMI connected projector.)

What we tried:
1. F2 to lower brightness – works somewhat, but only to low brightness not to blackout.
2  "Display have separate Spaces" enabled or disabled – does not work; in both cases, the primary screen does not go to black.
3. The shortcut Shift-Control-Esc – does not work, sets the secondary display (or both) to black (not the primary display  even the active window and the mouse is on the primary display) 
4. "Hot Corners: Put display to Sleep" – does not work, blacks out both screens.

How can we black out only the main (internal, primary) screen?

At the moment, I am putting VLC in separate space and have set a black desktop background, but there must be a better solution...

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

VLC Prefs > video > Black screens in fullscreen mode

[image]

This may require you to also change your Mission Control Spaces behaviour.
You may need to **uncheck** this. 
Mine works with this unchecked. I cannot test if it works checked as it badly messes up my workflow to change it.

[image]